# In blade script how can i use php arrya and pass there a javascript key?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

In some.blade.php I receive inputs from front-end and if any of those end with '_script' I should create editors for them. The main problem that I initialize those editor in . So I cannot pass a key to php array.
In template, I use jslogic. There I pass each array element (editors). init_editor is a js library.

```
@section('content')
    @php
        $tempvr = 'selection_rules_script';
        
        $editorVariablesNames = [];

        foreach ($entity->attr as $attributeSlug => $attribute) {
            if(strpos($attribute['slug'], '_script') !== false) {
               $editorVariablesNames[$attribute['slug']] = $attribute['slug'].'_editor';
            }
        }
    @endphp
    <div class="filter shadow-md bg-white border border-gray-120 rounded-md p-10 text-sm text-gray-900 font-bold">
            <form id="form" action="{{route('entities.update', ['entity' => $entity])}}" method="POST"
                  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @method('put')
               
                @foreach ($entity->attr as $attributeSlug => $attribute)
                    @if ($attribute['type'] === 'TextValue')
                        @if (strpos($attributeSlug, '_script') !== false)
                            <div class=""
                                 id="{{$attributeSlug}}_editor">{{$attribute['value']}}</div>
                            <textarea id="{{$attributeSlug}}_textarea" class="hidden"
                                      name="attr_{{$attributeSlug}}"></textarea>
                            <x-jslogic::externalsTree
                                    :script_editor="$editorVariablesNames[$attributeSlug]"
                                    :externalsTree="$externalsTrees[$attributeSlug]"
                                    :slug="$attributeSlug"/>
                        @else
                            <textarea
                                    class=""
                                    name="attr_{{$attribute['slug']}}"
                            >{{$attribute['value']}}</textarea>
                        @endif
                    @else
                        <input class=""
                               type="text" name="attr_{{$attribute['slug']}}"
                               value="{{$attribute['value']}}">
                    @endif
                @endforeach
                <p class="pt-8 mt-8 grid justify-items-center w-full border-t border-gray-200">
                    <button class="apply-button" type="submit">Save</button>
                </p>
            </form>
    </div>
```

The script which creates editors

```
    <script>
        function hasRuleScript(ruleScript) {
            return document.getElementById(ruleScript + '_editor') !== null;
        }

        function getRulesScripts() {
            let rulesScripts = []
            const rulesAttributes = {!! json_encode($entity->attr) !!};
            for(const ruleScript in rulesAttributes) {
                if (ruleScript.endsWith('_script')) {
                    rulesScripts.push(ruleScript);
                }
            }

            return rulesScripts;
        }

        function defineRulesScriptsFields() {
            for(const ruleScript of getRulesScripts()) {
                if(hasRuleScript(ruleScript)) {
                    {{$tempvr}} = ruleScript;
                    console.log({{$tempvr}})
```

Here is the problem. I need to pass ruleScript (which is the key) to $editorVariablesNames array

```
                    {{$editorVariablesNames[$tempvr]}} = init_editor(ruleScript + '_editor');
                    console.log({{$editorVariablesNames[$tempvr]}}.getValue())

                    const form = document.getElementById("form");
                    form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
                        document.getElementById(ruleScript + '_textarea').value = {{$editorVariablesNames[$tempvr]}}.getValue();
                    }, false);
                }
            }
        }

        defineRulesScriptsFields()
    </script>
@endsection
```

Comment: you can't assign a JS variable to a PHP variable. PHP is server side and JS is client side. the opposite is possible